# How to find element of div from another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the elements in the div as mentioned below:

```
   <div id="container">
     <div id="first_div">
        <div id="comment-1" class="comment">Child 1 of first div</div>
        <div id="comment-2" class="comment">Child 2 of first div</div>
        <div id="comment-3" class="comment">Child 3 of first div</div>
        <div id="comment-4" class="comment">Child 4 of first div</div>
     </div>
     <div id="second_div">
        <div id="comment-5" class="comment">Child 1 of second div</div>
        <div id="comment-6" class="comment">Child 2 of second div</div>
        <div id="comment-7" class="comment">Child 3 of second div</div>
        <div id="comment-8" class="comment">Child 4 of second div</div>
     </div>
     <div id="third_div">
        <div id="comment-9" class="comment">Child 1 of third div</div>
        <div id="comment-10" class="comment">Child 2 of third div</div>
        <div id="comment-11" class="comment">Child 3 of third div</div>
        <div id="comment-12" class="comment">Child 4 of third div</div>
     </div>
```

I need to retrieve the next element from comment id comment-4.

`$('#comment-4').next().attr('id')` gives me result as undefined.I need the target div to be comment id - comment-5.How to retrieve the next element of div from another div using jquery?

Comment: Do you want to get `id="comment-5"`?

Comment: which div do you want to target??

Comment: at what event you want to find comment div?

Comment: please share jsfiddle.

Comment: You'd have to check for `next` first. If there's none, go up the DOM, look for the parent's `next()`, then go for its first child.

Comment: Why don't you just match $(".comment") and do `eq()`?

Comment: Could you do a jsFiddle Please, also you could uses the class to find the ids by looping, $().each(function(){});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4xheS/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.comment').click(function(index){
      var id;
      if ( $(this).is(':last-child') )
          id = $(this).parent().next().children(':first').attr('id');
       else
          id = $(this).next().attr('id'); 
       alert(id);    
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bShX/11/)**

Comment: Happy to help you. Can you please accept this answer if this is what you were looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/PU54r/

```
function nextOf(id,cyclic){
  var ids= $('div[id^=comment-]').toArray().map(function(e){return $(e).attr('id')}).sort();
  var idx=ids.indexOf("comment-"+id);
   if(idx!==-1){
      if(ids.length> idx+1){
        return $('div#'+ids[idx]);
      }   
       else{

            // it is the last div: if it is cyclic ,you may return the first 
            if(cyclic){
                return $('div#'+ids[0]);
            }
      }
   }else{
       // no div with this id
    }
  
}
```

Then :

```
var target=nextOf(4)  
if(target){
  target.html()
  //--> Child 1 of second div
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `$('.comment')` to pick up all of your wanted, and save them in some variable such as `var arrResult = $('.comment');`.

So far, you can choose what you wanted use the `arrResult` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because your inner-most `div`s have different parents, I would first get all the divs you care about:

```
var comments = $('.comment');
```

Next, if we can assume your id's are all numbered sequentially, get the number in the id (assuming `this` references the element):

```
var index = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substr(8));
```

Now, the next div in the comment list is at that position in the comments:

```
var nextDiv = comments[index];
```

Just for good measure, I'd first make sure `index` is set:

```
var nextDiv;
if (index < comments.length) {
  nextDiv = comments[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an index in your case :

JS:

```
for (var index = 0; index <= 12; ++index) {
    $("#comment-" + index).attr("id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this will be undefined: `$('#comment-4').next().attr('id')` because there is no next element. as you mentioned that you want to target the `#comment-5` in the next div's child then you can do this:

```
function giveId(el) {
    var sel = el.id ? '#'+el.id : '.'+el.className;
    var id = $(sel).next('div').length ? $(sel).next('div').attr('id') : $(sel).parent('div').next('div').find('> div:first').attr('id');

    return id || "Either no next elem exist or next elem doesnot have any id/class.";
}


$(function () {
    $('div').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert(giveId(this));
    });
});
```

### [Updated Demo in action](http://jsfiddle.net/CfzAa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jQuery-wrapped element is collected in `$comment`, there's one way to solve it:

```
function getNextComment($comment) {
  var $nextComment = $comment.next();
  if ($nextComment.length) {
    return $nextComment;
  }

  var $nextParent = $comment.parent().next();
  if ($nextParent.length) {
    return $nextParent.children().first(); 
  }

  return null;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T3hyS/). Click on one comment - and see the next one's highlighted. )

The base algorithm's very simple here. First, we attempt to retrieve the next sibling of the given element. If there's one, it's returned immediately. If not (and it's the case with `#comment-4` in your question - it's the *last* element in its hierarchy), we go up the DOM chain for its parent (`#first-div`, in this case), and look for *its* next sibling (`#second-div`). If it exists, then its very first child element is returned. If it doesn't, `null` is returned (we can actually return an empty jQuery object - `$()`, but that depends on use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a statement which checks the target id is the last child, than you can return a function according to value.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tfcFj/2/)

```
var target = 'comment-4';
$('.comment').each(function(i) {
    if ( $(this).attr('id') == target ) {

        if ( $(this).is(':last-child') ) {
            $(this).parent().next().children().first().addClass('red');
        }else{
            $(this).next().addClass('red');
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is showing undefined because `comment-4` and `comment-5` are childrens of different parent elements. Means `comment-4` is children of `first_div` and `second_div` parent of  `comment-5`.

You can get the `comment-5` using below code.

```
$('#comment-4').parent().next().children().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/WLeSr/

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var highlight = $('.highlight');
    var currentIndex = $('.comment').index(highlight); // get the index of the currently highlighted item
    $('.comment').removeClass('highlight'); 
    var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    $('.comment').eq(nextIndex).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just one instruction : )

```
$('<div id="mock" />').append($('.comment').clone()).find('#comment-4').next().attr('id')//---> comment-5
```

Based on divs have the same Css class `.comment`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/PU54r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhd_reza/vS9bC/) (The easiest solution!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currDiv = $("#comment-4"); // Try with different valies: "#comment-x"
    currDivId = currDiv.prop('id');
    lastDivId = currDiv.parent('div').find('.comment').last().prop('id');
    if(currDivId == lastDivId){
        var nextComment = currDiv.parent('div').next('div').find('.comment').prop('id');
    }else{
        var nextComment = currDiv.parent('div').find('.comment').next().prop('id');
    }
    alert(nextComment); 
});
```